# React Native Admob library crash and gradle doesn't build

Tags: react-native, google-api, sdk, admob, adsense

I need to setup admob in my application
I use react native v0.57.3
I have installed lets see:

**app/build.gralde**:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-admob')

    implementation project(':react-native-imei')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0") {
        force = true
    }

    implementation project(':react-native-view-shot')

}
```

**settings.gradle**:

```
include ':react-native-admob'
project(':react-native-admob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-admob/android')
```

**mainApplication.java**:

```
import com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage;
and
new RNAdMobPackage()
```

**menifest**:

***in application tag***:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="APP ID"/>
```

When I try to build gradle I get this error:
Compilation failed to complete

Anyone can help me please??

**Error**
When I comment this line // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6" I get this error "Compilation failed to complete"

**But If I leave it I get this error:**
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0.
5]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.4 -> com.google.android.gms:play-servic
es-measurement-base@[16.0.5], but play-services-measurement-base version was 16.3.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@+
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.6

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.

Comment: Did you check for Syntax errors?

Comment: We need the complete error, Compilation failed to complete is just the start of the error, post a screenshot of the error ;)

Comment: @FouadAlbadin edit your question and paste in your error. Adding them in the comments is not what the comments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because your react-native-addmob and react-native-firebase might be using different version of google play services and base version. Match the version better probably it will fit around `15.x.x`. Check that.

Moreover why do you need a react-native-admob? As per as I know react-native-firebase provide admob. I would suggest you to use firebase service for that since you already have that library integrated.
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/admob/reference/admob

Comment: Thank you I have used firebase.admob and there are no errors but I comment firebase.core is this will let me face a problems? I only use massaging and phone auth in addition to ads

Comment: But the ad doesn''t load I get this alert onAdFailedToLoad "The ad request was successful l, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory"

Comment: Also please do not forgot to like my answer if it helps you

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I set a question on stackoverflow yes ofcourse I will

Comment: This page "stackoverflow.com/a/8792358/1868389" is not useful for me do you thunk because I am in debug mode so the ad will lot load? How to get test app id?

Comment: I have get test app id and the ads have run I will try to export release app with my app Id thank you very much for your first advice